# How does SQL Server internally rename a table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014, we are performing some operations which require re-building a table structure. We have narrowed down our approach to two methods:

1. Create new "temporary" table (Not the `#TempTable` kind), dump data into temp table, delete original, then dump the data back.
2. Rename existing table, create new table, then dump the data from temp to new.

My colleague insists #1 is the ideal option to choose. However, I'm convinced that #1 will take twice as much time as #2 (since we have BLOB data consuming massive storage). Colleague claims that when you rename a table, internally, SQL Server creates a new table and dumps the data over anyway. I highly disagree. I'm sure that SQL Server just simply modifies the name of the existing table. While searching for how this actually works, I cannot find any information.

So how does SQL Server internally rename a table? Does it create a new table, dump the data, then delete the old one? Or does it simply modify the name?

Comment: If by temp table you mean #tempTable which is only good for the connection and scope is limited to such I wouldn't go this route since you could lose all the data.

Comment: @scsimon No, not SQL Server's definition of a "Temp Table".

Comment: then option 2 still. I can't find documentation but I have never heard anything close to the first logic and can't imagine why SQL Server would behave this way.

Comment: @scsimon That's exactly what I figured. That's a very silly claim. But he's older and is the lead developer, so it's difficult to argue with him :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it make sense?

```
sp_helptext 'sp_rename'
```

Comment: Or more specifically, within that SP, the line `EXEC %%Object(ID = @objid).SetName(Name = @newname)`

Comment: @JerryDodge To be honest, I reviewed sp_rename stored procedure for the first time. As you said, looks like it updates the table name only in sysobjects table. Good idea :)